Expo prevent audio recording while a call is in progress on Android using Expo AV in React Native
When I’m on a call and try to send a voice message, iOS works perfectly and doesn’t allow it. However, on Android, it is possible to record and send audio while a call is in progress. My question is: is there a way to prevent audio recording during a call on Android?
export const audio = (idChat?: string) => {
    // const { onRecordingAudio } = ChatWebSocket();
    const { setModalError } = useAlertError();
 
    const verifyPermissions = async () => {
        return (await Audio.getPermissionsAsync()).status === 'granted';
    }
 
    const setPermissions = async () => {
        const permission = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (permission.status == 'denied') {
            setModalError(modalConstants.modalErrorPermissionAudioHeyLinx)
        }
        return permission.granted;
    }
 
    const setConfigAudio = async () => {
        try {
            await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
                allowsRecordingIOS: true,
                playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
                interruptionModeIOS: InterruptionModeIOS.DoNotMix,
                interruptionModeAndroid: InterruptionModeAndroid.DoNotMix,
            });
 
        } catch (error) {
            setModalError(modalConstants.modalErrorConfigAudioHeyLinx)
        }
    }
 
    const recordAudio = async (recording: Audio.Recording) => {
        try {
            // onRecordingAudio(idChat, true);
            await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY);
            await recording.startAsync();
            return recording;
        } catch (error) {
            recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
            setModalError(modalConstants.modalErrorRecordingHeyLinx);
        }
    }
 
    const stopRecording = async (recording: Audio.Recording) => {
        try {
            // onRecordingAudio(idChat, false);
            await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
            await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
                allowsRecordingIOS: false,
                playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            
 

I expect that on Android, it should also not be possible to send voice messages while a call is in progress.
